# migrating from Xamarin 4 to Xamarin 5

Tags: xamarin.forms

I just update all my nugget packages to Xamarinforms 5.0.0.2012, Xamarin Maps 5.0.0.2012, Xamarin.Forms.Visual.Material 5.0.0.2012, Xamarin Essentials 1.61 and prism 8.0.0.1909,..  all my packages and even my VS to the lastet version 16.9.3

Now when I run (f5) my android project on my samsung note 9,by usb,  in the splash screen I got this error:

*Java.Lang.RuntimeException   Mensaje = Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.XXX.yyyyyy-xjKonazvnj9Dk6-OE4QIZQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.XXX.yyyyyy-xjKonazvnj9Dk6-OE4QIZQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.XXX.yyyyyy-xjKonazvnj9Dk6-OE4QIZQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]*

and then the app hungs and got closed

thanks

Comment: Did you migrate your Android project to AndroidX and verified if all your nugget packages are compatible with it?

Comment: no,... how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade your project from Xamarin.Forms 4.0 to 5.0 you have to migrate your Android project to `AndroidX` as well, which means that all `Android.Support` libraries changed to `AndroidX` libraries.

The crash error you posted shows that your project still have references to old `Android.Support` namespaces.

Microsoft provides some articles about how to migrate your app.
It's pretty straghtfoward and most of the process is done automatically for you:

[AndroidX migration in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration)

[How do I migrate my app to Xamarin.Forms 5.0?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms5-migration)

Answer (score 0):

Well thaks for the guide,...
The solution was easy

1. Open the AndroidManifest.xml
2. Search for **android.support.v4.content.FileProvider**
3. Replace  in every place for **androidx.core.content.FileProvider**
4. Save and rebuild, that's all

Hope this help to someone

Comment: Or try the [Migrator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/visual-studio-2019-version-16-4/#android-x-migration-wizard) in VS, when there are lots of packages.